# Add new document to R corpus to find unique words

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I have a corpus of speeches and I would like to identify the unique words within one kind of speeches.

This is what I did, I extracted two corpora from the larger one. In the script EUP_control_corpus and IMF_control_corpus. I made IMF_control_corpus into one text file which I want to combine with EUP_control_corpus, then by using tf.idf I want to find out which terms are unique for the IMF speeches in relation to EUP speeches.

However, I'm stuck at the part of adding to (combining with) a corpus. To me it seems like this should be very simple so I don't understand why I can't find anything on it. Is it so simple that no-one has asked this question?

I tried making both into a dfm and then joining them, or turning the text file back into a corpus to join them, but in both instances, the single text file turned out to have, once more, a great number of documents.

```
  #Create date format
base_corpus$documents$int_date <- 
  as.Date( base_corpus$documents$date,  format = "%d-%m-%Y")
head(as.Date( base_corpus$documents$date,  format = "%d-%m-%Y"))


#Select pre-crisis EUP speeches for control group
EUP_control_corpus<- 
  corpus_subset(base_corpus, country == "European Parliament" & int_date < as.Date( '31-12-2012', format = "%d-%m-%Y"))
head(docnames(EUP_control_corpus), 50)
ndoc(EUP_control_corpus)


#Create dfm out of EUP corpus
EUP_control_dfm <- 
  dfm(EUP_control_corpus, tolower = TRUE, stem = FALSE)
ndoc(EUP_control_dfm)


#Select pre-crisis IMF speeches for control group
IMF_control_corpus<- 
  corpus_subset(base_corpus, country == "International Monetary Fund" & int_date < as.Date( '31-12-2012', format = "%d-%m-%Y"))
head(docnames(IMF_control_corpus), 50)
ndoc(IMF_control_corpus)


#Combine IMF_control_corpus into one text
IMF_control_text<-
  texts(corpus(texts(IMF_control_corpus, groups = "texts")))
IMF_control_dfm<-
  dfm(IMF_control_text)
ndoc(IMF_control_dfm)


#Add IMF_control_text to EUP_control_dfm
plus_dfm<-
  dfm(rbind(EUP_control_dfm, IMF_control_dfm))
ndoc((plus_dfm))


#Add IMF_control_text to EUP_control_corpus/ doesn't work, make text into single text corpus and then add?
total_control_corpus<-
  corpus(EUP_control_corpus, IMF_control_text)
ndoc(total_control_corpus)
```

I have the idea that the group function in quanteda could be useful to do this in another way, but I decided to post the question first as have been on the search for a couple of days already.

Thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a question with a reproducible example, so it is hard to provide a correct answer.  Here are some suggestions:

1. Create a new document variable called `control` that takes on one of two values, `IMF` or `EU`.  Use this using the conditionals that you were previously using with the `corpus_subset()` command.  From that, you can easily create a dfm that will continue to include this docvar, or you can use the `groups = "control"` argument to `dfm()` to collapse the counts by the values of this variable.
2. Use `docvars(thecorpus, "thevariable") <- newvalue` instead of addressing the inner contents of the corpus object.  That method is not stable since we may change the internal contents of the corpus at any time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer brought me to the idea to use an existing docvar as conditionality. I combined the IMF en EUP corpus and then used groups in dfm() the include the conditionality. This resulted in a dfm with two document with the name TRUE and FALSE. Can I keep the integrity of EUP the documents?

 #Combine
control_corpus <- 
  c(EUP_control_corpus, IMF_control_corpus, recursive = FALSE)


#dfm
control_dfm <- 
  dfm(control_corpus, groups = c(control_corpus$documents$country == "International Monetary Fund"))
ndoc(control_dfm)
head(docnames(control_dfm))

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It might not be the prettiest one, but it works.

```
#Loop through the corpus and paste all documents into one document
temp <- IMF_control_corpus$documents$texts[1]

for(i in 2:337){
  temp <- paste(temp,IMF_control_corpus$documents$texts[i])
}

#Create corpus out of text and add docvars, make sure it looks the same as EUP_control_corpus
single_IMF_corpus <- corpus(temp)
single_IMF_corpus$documents$title      <- "IMF Text"
single_IMF_corpus$documents$date       <- "" 
single_IMF_corpus$documents$country    <- "International Monetary Fund"
single_IMF_corpus$documents$speaker    <- "IMF"
single_IMF_corpus$documents$length     <- ""
single_IMF_corpus$documents$language   <- "en"
single_IMF_corpus$documents$language2  <- "english"
single_IMF_corpus$documents$int_date   <- as.Date("", format = "%d-%m-%Y")


#Combine single_IMF_corpus and EUP_control_corpus
total_control_corpus<-
 c(EUP_control_corpus, single_IMF_corpus)
ndoc(total_control_corpus)
ndoc(EUP_control_corpus)
```